# Getting Youtube data is slow on mobile data connection, to proxy?

Tags: php, android, xml, proxy

I have just made a simple app that pulls down a users videos e.g.

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/daxx2k/uploads
```

It works fine when on a speedy wifi connection but is very slow on mobile, I know it depends greatly on reception etc but it is usually very slow.

I am trying to come up with ways to speed up the access and I have realised that there is no way to reduce the amount of XML coming back so I am thinking it may be efficient to proxy the data through my own server.

I could write a simple PHP script that is called from Android and outputs only the fields that  it needs, video { name, url, date, duration, thumbnail }.

I imagine the speed would be much higher and I would also have a layer of abstraction. If Youtube changed something (unlikely) I could just fix my side but the outputted fields would remain the same.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one server its a single point of failure. You will also need to handle the traffic and the bandwidth and housing will cost you money.

I would rather play with [Youtube API Demo](http://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html) and see what is the best. For example use json instead of xml. Or jsonc but for that you need to manually change the query and it is not available for all queries.

---

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/users/daxx2k/uploads?format=1,6&v=2 [9.3KB]
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/users/daxx2k/uploads?alt=json&format=1,6&v=2 [9.2KB]
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/users/daxx2k/uploads?alt=jsonc&format=1,6&v=2 [5KB]

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/users/daxx2k/uploads?format=1,6 [7.5KB]
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/users/daxx2k/uploads?alt=json&format=1,6 [7.5KB]

Comment: I agree with you on the issues with a server. I have just played with the API and don't see a way of improving. You can't seem to be able to select the fields that come back in the response. In fact selecting mobile returns 20k chars extra. To alleviate the hosting issues I could use a cron to update a static file hosted on my S3. That would be neat.

Comment: added links with transferred bytes count

Comment: Fair enough, that's what i'm currently using but it's still pretty slow. Let's just say it's the mobile. I'll try some benchmarks in the app. Thanks for your time.